# How to find saddle point of a matrix in java?

Tags: java

Saddle point of a matrix is an element in the matrix which is smallest in its row and largest in its column. For example,

```
6    3    1
9    7    8
2    4    5
```

Comment: but its only one row

Comment: @DonatoAmasa - did you check for formatting problems?

Comment: How?  Iterate over all of the elements, and test each one if it is a saddle point.

Comment: sorry i did not

Answer (score 2):

#### Find Sattle Point

1. Find the smallest element in a row and store it in rowMin and also store its column index in colIndex.
2. Check whether rowMin is also the largest element in its column i.e colIndex.
3. When rowMin is also the largest element in its column declare it as saddle point.
4. Do the steps for all rows of your matrix

---

```
static void findSaddlePoint(int[][] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) 
        {
            int rowMin = matrix[i][0];
             
            int colIndex = 0;
             
            boolean saddlePoint = true;
             
            //Finding the smallest element in ith row
             
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j] < rowMin)
                {
                    rowMin = matrix[i][j];
                     
                    colIndex = j;
                }
            }
             
            //Checking rowMin is also the largest element in its column
             
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
            {
                if(matrix[j][colIndex] > rowMin)
                {
                    saddlePoint = false;
                     
                    break;
                }
            }
             
            if(saddlePoint)
            {
                System.out.println("Saddle Point is : "+rowMin);
            }
        }
```

#### Run It

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int[][] matrix = {{6,3,1},{9,7,8},{2,4,5}};

  <Class>.findSaddlePoint(matrix);
}
```

#### Output

```
Saddle Point is : 7
```

- Here the full example
  [https://javaconceptoftheday.com/find-saddle-point-of-a-matrix-in-java/#:~:text=Step%201%20%3A%20For%20each%20row,its%20column%20index%20in%20colIndex.&text=Step%202%20%3A%20Check%20whether%20rowMin,in%20its%20column%20i.e%20colIndex](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/find-saddle-point-of-a-matrix-in-java/#:%7E:text=Step%201%20%3A%20For%20each%20row,its%20column%20index%20in%20colIndex.&text=Step%202%20%3A%20Check%20whether%20rowMin,in%20its%20column%20i.e%20colIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the matrix and find minimum in the row (its index) and maximum in the column, if the indexes are equal, the saddle point is found.

A sample algorithm to find and print a saddle point in a square array is as follows:

```java
static boolean hasSaddlePoint(int[][] arr) {
    boolean saddleFound = false;
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        int minId = 0, maxId = 0;
        for (int j = 0, m = arr[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            // find index of minimum element in row
            if (arr[i][j] < arr[i][minId]) {
                minId = j;
            }
            if (arr[j][i] > arr[maxId][i]) {
                maxId = j;
            }
        }
        if (minId == maxId) {
            System.out.printf("Saddle point arr[%d][%d] = %d%n", maxId, minId, arr[maxId][minId]);
            saddleFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (!saddleFound) {
        System.out.println("No saddle point found");
    }
    return saddleFound;
}
```

Test:

```java
hasSaddlePoint(new int[][]{
  {6,    3,    1},
  {9,    7,    8},
  {2,    4,    5}
});
```

prints

```
Saddle point arr[1][1] = 7
```